# Django accessing the database with specific model in template

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to access the database in my template and so far I have been unsuccessful.

Here is my model class I've been trying access:

```
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    redirect_url = models.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="URL to redirect to when Questionnaire is complete. Macros: $SUBJECTID, $RUNID, $LANG", default="/static/complete.html")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def questionsets(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "__qscache"):
            self.__qscache = \
              QuestionSet.objects.filter(questionnaire=self).order_by('sortid')
        return self.__qscache

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("export", "Can export questionnaire answers"),
            ("management", "Management Tools")
        )
```

Here is what my `views.py` looks like:

```
def question_list(request):
    question_info = Questionnaire.objects.all()

    question_data = {
        "question_detail" : question_info
    }

 print question_data
 return render_to_response('questionnaire/templates/quizzes.html', question_data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and finally my template `quizzes.html`:

```
{% for question in question_detail %}
<h3>{{ question.name }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Have you HTML and BODY start and end tags? Have a look at the raw output (Ctrl-u in browser)

Comment: The body and HTML tags all work I have a working template the only that thing that is not working is that the data is not displaying with that for loop in my template

Answer (score 0):

Is not simpler this way?

views.py:

```
def question_list(request):
    questions = Questionnaire.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('questionnaire/templates/quizzes.html',{'questions':questions}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

.html

```
{% for question in questions %}
<h3>{{ question.name }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```